# How to use dot "." notation in table field in flink

Tags: sql, apache-flink

I'm querying the Flink table which contains columns in "." notation.
How do I query a table like -> `select source.ip from sourceTable;`

Comment: Is `source.ip` a nested field or not?

Comment: Nope they are not. It's a flattered json of nested objects.

Comment: yes It is flattened json 
{"source.ip":"10.20.10.10", "source.name":"zxc"}
{"source.ip":"10.20.10.20", "source.name":"abc"}

and table is like this
source.ip         source.name
10.20.10.10 zxc
10.20.10.20     abc

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.
we can use back tick for source.ip like

```
select * from (back tick)source.ip(back tick) from sourceTable;
```

Comment: `select * from \`source.ip\` from sourceTable;`